# Is it possible to get the file path to the .blend file that a linked object came from programmatically?

Tags: python, scripting, linked-data, append

I am trying to find a list of all file paths that are appended/linked in a .blend file through the Blender API, I need to run a script in each appended/linked file to change materials so in turn the material would be changed in the source file.

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it is possible:

```
obj.library.filepath
```

Additionnally, a not linked object has an empty `obj.library`.